# How to export object outline as DWG or SVG lines without modifying mesh?

Tags: export, grease-pencil, freestyle, lineart

I was wondering if there was a way to export object outlines as displayed in the viewport as SVG/DWG lines. I'm aware of the Line Art modifier for greasepencil object but there are some issues with it that I can't resolve.

This is the desired output (exactly the same as viewport display)
[image]

This is using greasepencil's Line Art modifier.
As you can see it's not fully outlined.
[image]

It has other issues like this as well.
[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: There is no such functionality currently in Blender. Grease pencil is as good as it gets to do this even though it's not very good.

Answer (score 4):

There used to be a better add-on for this. But maybe this is suitable:

Find this Freestyle SVG Exporter add-on in Preferences and enable it.
[image]

In Render Properties, enable Freestyle SVG Export and Freestyle:
[image]

In View Layer Properties, enable Export Strokes and select edge type settings as shown.
[image]

Now upon rendering your scene, blender will save an svg file of the external contour in your output directory.

Examples:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a problem with Geometry Processing or Chaining. Can you share your .blend file? So we can investigate farther.

Compare Line Art on flat surface and smooth surface without Crease On Smooth option:
[image: Compare Line Art on flat surface and smooth surface without Crease On Smooth option]

Comment: I would really like to avoid using greasepencil for this, blender already outlines the objects perfectly in the viewport so I was wondering if there was a way to programmatically extract that info. Unfortunately I can't share the files due to nda.